# Cannot set property field_map of #<Calendar> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

facing problem while using  Object.assign

```
/* called from some where */
this.calendar = new myapp.views.Calendar(options);

export class Calendar {
    constructor(options) {
        Object.assign(this, options);
        this.get_default_options();
    } 
 ...
}

myapp.view.calendar = Calendar;
```

Error:
Cannot set property field_map of # which has only a getter

Comment: `Object.assign(this, options);` is likely trying to set `field_map` which only has a getter.

Comment: can you explain new to js

Comment: `Object.assign` merges two or more objects together. `options` likely contains a property called `field_map`, which for some reason is read-only. Although I'm only making guesses since the provided example does not actually say.

Comment: it means if any key(field_map) having getter method like ``` get field_map{...}``` is treated as constant right and we can not change that right.

Comment: Not unless we overwrite the property. `Object.defineProperty` would do it.